# How to execute JavaScript on UserControl PostBack in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

We have an asp.net page that consists of multiple user controls, many of which have the `visible` attribute set to `false`.
By selecting a radio button, one of the user controls is shown by setting the `visible` attribute to `true` in the code-behind. When this happens, we want a JavaScript function to be run. The script has been registered using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript` in the `Page_Load` method of the page.

How can we make this work?

Things we've tried:

- Register script in the user control (both code-behind and markup)
- Trying some of the other methods available on the `ScriptManager`
- Using jQuery `$(document).ready()`

But in all cases the script is only executed when the page is loaded/reloaded.
The only *hack* that seems to work, is calling the function inside the `pageLoad()` function as this function gets called after every PostBack.

Comment: First suspicion is that the RegisterStartupScript call may be in your Page_Load within a !Page.IsPostback block, which would prevent it from being run. Could you possibly post your code-behind?

Comment: The RegisterStartupScript is the first statement inside Page_Load. It is not possible for me to post the entire file right now.

Comment: I'm not sure what else is going on in your code , but an easy fix is to control the radio buttons all on client side, then run js on client side as well , this prevents an unecessary trip to server side (unless of course there is other code that makes server side code necessary)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I was not able to make this work quite the way I wanted. Instead I have now changed the application so that no UpdatePanels or PostBacks are necessary. That makes things more predictable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to include the user control inside an updatePanel and add your ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript inside the updatePanel load event:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" 
OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load">
```

c#

```
protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //your code to fire the javascript
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. Once my script has been executed once, it will not be executed until I register it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the server side: `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` with client side: `setTimeout()`

For example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
    string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello World")},3000);</script>";

    if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert"))
    {
            page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(PageFunctions), "alert", script);
    }
}
```

This will register a script block on page_load and after 3 secs the alert will be displayed see more about setTimeout @ [Window setTimeout() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: If you understand how to work with setTimeout() you can create a js method to run after page loads and that method can apply a handler to selecting event of you radio button, all this at runtime.

Comment: using setTimeout() to wait for asynchronous events is poor programing since you don't actually know how long it's gonna take and you are creating a racing condition in your code